# how to write regular expression for finding <@> in the whole paragraph?

Tags: javascript, regex

how to find the exact match of the following pattern "test <@4340875d-f56d-4a2f-9b99-3f090a878eb4>". from the string I want find whether it is starting with < and it has @ or not and the ending should be >.
I'm using the below pattern it is detecting HTML tags too.

```
/[@<>]+/g;
```

In my case I want find only <@ > this pattern is there are not. how i can find in javascript?

Comment: as you described `/<.+?>/g`

Comment: Why did you attempt to use `/[@<>]+/g`? Have you looked up the regex syntax to understand what that pattern would match? [What has your research led to?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Can you give examples of text that should match and examples of text that should not?

Comment: Your question is unclear: first you say you want an exact match, then you say the `@` is optional. Please give a clearer description of what varieties you want to find and in which context they should be found (give us a larger sample of the code you are searching through).

Comment: Judging by the description, [`/<@[^>]*>/g`](https://regex101.com/r/aRYBo2/1) should work. But maybe [`/<[^<>]*@[^<>]*>/g`](https://regex101.com/r/aRYBo2/2) is what is really meant.

Comment: `it is detecting HTML tags too.` - To match `<@ >` directly inside an html document will never work. For example using this `<[^<>]*@[^<>]*>` matches `<a  b=@ >` and a thousand other ways it could match inside or overlay tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Regex you need:

```
/<@[^>]*>/g
```

- `<@` matches the characters <@ literally (case sensitive)
- Match a single character not present in the list below `[^>]*`, to avoid matching the `>` character between <>.
- `>` matches the character > literally
- **g** modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)

This is a [Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MnvaKV/1) and a Demo snippet:

```js
const regex = /<@[^>]*>/g;
const str = `<@4340875d-f56d-4a2f-9b99-3f090a878eb4>

<div>`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: You are welcome, I just explained and tested what [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew) suggested.

Comment: Matches <!--`<@-->`

Comment: Then it would be just `/^<@[^>]*>/g`.

Comment: Then won't match "a `<@-->`"

Comment: @sln In that case we can update it like this `[^@<!->]*(<@[^>]*>)` or even better `[\w]*(<@[^>]*>)` you can see it [working **here**](https://regex101.com/r/MnvaKV/3), but anyway the first one in the answer just solved his problems in his specific case. Why would we bother too much and try to complicate things?!

Comment: I believe he stated `I'm using the below pattern it is detecting HTML tags too`. Apparently he is trying to get it from an html doc. You state your regex is the one he needs and go on to describe in a detailed way, the simple regex syntax with a bullet point presentation. Yet you _fail_ to say it can't be done this way (I guess because you want some quick rep), and defend your answer in the light of facts I'm leaving as comments.  The _working here_ thing does not work in any way, it overlaps attributes here  https://regex101.com/r/MnvaKV/4 in the middle of tags https://regex101.com/r/7pjwRt/2

Answer (score -1):

I believe you want this:

```
/<@?.*>/
```

@? means 0 or 1 instances of @

.*> means 0 or infinite instances of any character up to >